# ld: warning: alignment lost in merging tentative definition _paused

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I got this warning when I archive my application on iOS target: 3.0
May be since I modified the build setting I got warnings.

```
Ld /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NanoWar2-epaqhmmjlngxpwaedknxqymopqbj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/NanoWar2/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/NanoWar2.build/Release-iphoneos/NanoWar2.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NanoWar2 normal armv7
    cd /Users/Benoit/Workshop/Dropbox/NanoWar2_Iphone
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 3.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -L/Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NanoWar2-epaqhmmjlngxpwaedknxqymopqbj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/NanoWar2/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/Benoit/Workshop/Dropbox/NanoWar2_Iphone/NanoWar2/libs/TestFlightSDK1.0 -F/Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NanoWar2-epaqhmmjlngxpwaedknxqymopqbj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/NanoWar2/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/Benoit/Workshop/Dropbox/NanoWar2_Iphone/NanoWar2/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NanoWar2-epaqhmmjlngxpwaedknxqymopqbj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/NanoWar2/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/NanoWar2.build/Release-iphoneos/NanoWar2.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NanoWar2.LinkFileList -dead_strip -lz -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -lz -framework GameKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework BugSense-iOS -framework CFNetwork -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lTestFlight -o /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NanoWar2-epaqhmmjlngxpwaedknxqymopqbj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/NanoWar2/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/NanoWar2.build/Release-iphoneos/NanoWar2.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NanoWar2

ld: warning: alignment lost in merging tentative definition _paused
ld: warning: alignment lost in merging tentative definition _paused
ld: warning: alignment lost in merging tentative definition _paused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed

I removed the external keyword from a .h file.

```
external BOOL paused
```

to

```
BOOL paused
```